# ¿Hay algún equivalente en castellano al prefijo inglés "robo-"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, prefijos

Con frecuencia en inglés leo cosas [*robo-reviewers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/209901) o [*robo-tweet*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/robo-) para referirse a cosas hechas automáticamente, o casi: revisar de forma automática, twits que hace una máquina...

Dictionary.com define este prefijo como:

> [**robo-**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/robo-)
>   a combining form extracted from robot and meaning "automated, automatic, or robotic," used in the formation of compound words:
>   *an automatically generated robo-tweet appearing in my Twitter feed;*
>   *a robo-advisor that provides algorithm-based investment advice.*

Y si bien la traducción directa podría ser *robo-*, pues se comparte etimología, me pregunto si existe algún prefijo en el castellano actual que cumpla esta función. O, si no, alguna palabra que funcione así a modo de coletilla.

Comment: El prefijo "robo-" se ha usado en español para las cosas automáticas, acuérdate de los "robocordones" de Regreso al Futuro 2.

Comment: Robot es una palabra nueva (apareció alrededor del 1920 y viene del checo "robotnik" gracias a Karel Čapek). Siendo tan nueva creo que es igual en todos los idiomas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalmente se utiliza para esto la palabra *robot* completa, antes o después, lo cual tiene distintas connotaciones: un *robot asesor* es un "robot" (un programa más o menos automatizado) que asesora, mientras que un *asesor robot* es un asesor que se caracteriza por no ser una persona sino un "robot".

Buscando en Google aparecen muchos avisos del tipo *robot limpiapiscinas*, *robot aspiradora*, etc. Aquí se usa la palabra para nombrar al hardware.

Una abreviatura muy común, cuando se trata sólo de software y especialmente uno que realiza procesos sencillos, es *bot*, igual que en inglés; como los *bots* que siguen a cuentas de Twitter o Instagram según ciertos perfiles o cuando mencionan alguna palabra clave.

Usar *robo-* como prefijo tiene el inconveniente de que es homónimo del delito de sustracción de propiedad. Lo he visto en marcas comerciales, que a veces por moda adoptan palabras del inglés, pero no me parece probable que un hablante de castellano se acostumbre a decir *roboauto* para referirse a un vehículo autónomo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Pablo. Lo mismo yo cogí el significado de un mal uso, pues mi primer contacto con este prefijo fue en la definición de [robo-reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/209901) de Meta SE: _As stated earlier, the main purpose of audits is to catch robo-reviewers, who mindlessly review without even looking at the posts, and to help educate new reviewers. Easy-to-identify audits help legitimate reviewers pass and help better hone new reviewers' skills_. Se trataría en este caso de alguien que hace algo de modo automático, sin pensar. ¿Será un mal uso del prefijo?

Comment: I would have called it a review-robot although that sounds fairly ugly to me too.

Comment: +1 especially for the bit about _roboauto_. That made me grin.